# What does suspend mean in Xubuntu 19.10?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I've recently been trying to fix [a strange sleep problem](https://superuser.com/q/1524979/865660) and have becoming aware that Xubuntu made some changes to how suspending works in 19.10. Because of this, I want to double-check something. When I press "Suspend" on the log out screen in Xubuntu 19.10, what sort of sleep/hibernation is actually being attempted? For example, is it trying to power off my computer?

Here's the output from syslog.log when I try (and fail) to suspend:

```
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3611] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3612] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC whoopsie[1521]: [22:55:17] offline
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC NetworkManager[1198]: <info>  [1581548117.3616] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC kernel: [ 8812.324175] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 12 22:55:17 MyPC systemd-sleep[16039]: Suspending system...
```

Does this suggest that something stronger than normal sleep is being attempted?

Comment: Suspend doesn't fully power of the system. It is a lo power state where RAM is powered. It is "suspend to RAM".

Comment: @Pilot6 Give me a source and I'll accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power management sleep states are described in the Linux kernel documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt). If you take a look in there, the `deep` sleep corresponds to:

```
State:      Suspend-to-RAM
ACPI State: S3
Label:      "deep"
```

And right below that, there's also a more detailed explanation of what this state is all about:

> This state, if supported, offers significant power savings as everything in the
>   system is put into a low-power state, except for memory, which should be placed
>   into the self-refresh mode to retain its contents.  All of the steps carried out
>   when entering Power-On Suspend are also carried out during transitions to STR.
>   Additional operations may take place depending on the platform capabilities.  In
>   particular, on ACPI systems the kernel passes control to the BIOS (platform
>   firmware) as the last step during STR transitions and that usually results in
>   powering down some more low-level components that aren't directly controlled by
>   the kernel.
>
> System and device state is saved and kept in memory.  All devices are suspended
>   and put into low-power states.  In many cases, all peripheral buses lose power
>   when entering STR, so devices must be able to handle the transition back to the
>   "on" state.